# Confusion in Spring Framework modularity

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing small JavaFX application that will use spring framework as it's DI container. Backend part will use `Oracle 11gR2` database, but I'm confused which spring module I should choose to connect to Oracle - I'm going to use only `JdbcTemplate`, ORM is not an option.

I read a bit of `Spring in Action 4` and author shows all modules that are present in "current" spring versions which was 4 at the moment of writing the book (picture below). So at first look it seems that I should add `spring-jdbc-VERSION`, but when I searched in google with connecting to oracle [I found another spring project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc-ext/) from spring data umbrella projects which points me to add `spring-data-oracle` dependency which is 2 years old and had no update since.

Does `spring-jdbc` include `spring-data-oracle` ? Can anyone explain it to me ?
Eventually what I should add to project to reach my goal ?

[image]

Comment: JdbcTemplate is part of spring-jdbc. So add spring-jdbc to your project dependencies, and Gradle or Maven will figure out the rest of spring jars to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need the JDBC-Template you need

1. the Oracle JDBC Driver
2. the `spring-jdbc` dependency (it itself uses `spring-core`, `spring-tx` etc.)

To manage all dependencies automatically use a dependency management tool such as maven or gradle.

gradle:

```
compile `org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.0.RELEASE`
```

maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Have a look at the getting started series - they include an example using the jdbc-template (including dependency management etc): https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/